# How to select nth element from more than one variable

Tags: r

Is it possible to select the nth element from more than one variable within one command?

For example: I have 2 variables `Romania_Pollen$V23` and `Romania_Pollen$V24`.

```
> Romania_Pollen$V23
 [1] S174883             230       1                   174883    --/596/--
 [8] --/597/-- 2                             90                  1        
[15] 4         1                   43                                     
[22]           13                            1                            
[29]                     7         1                                      
[36]                               55        1                            
[43]                                                                      
[50] 1                   1                                                
[57]                                                   1         1        
[64]                     1                   18                           
[71]           1         20        1                             7        
[78]           1         2                   1         1         2        
[85]                                         1                            
[92] 2                                       1                            
[99]          
Levels:  --/596/-- --/597/-- 1 13 174883 18 2 20 230 4 43 55 7 90 S174883
```

and then

```
> Romania_Pollen$V24
 [1] S174884             240       1                   174884    --/621/--
 [8] --/613/-- 4                             110                 1        
[15] 2         1                   100                                    
[22]           18                                                         
[29]                     12        2                                      
[36]                               58                  1                  
[43]                                                   1                  
[50]                               1                                      
[57]                                                   8         1        
[64]                     3         1         13                           
[71]           1         33        1                                      
[78]           1         3                   1                   1        
[85]                               1         1                            
[92] 1         1                                                          
[99]          
18 Levels:  --/613/-- --/621/-- 1 100 110 12 13 174884 18 2 240 3 33 4 58 ... S174884
```

Now, is it possible to select the 3rd variable of each variable (`V$23`, `V$24`)?

The thing is, I have 99 variables and would like to make  a vector out of the nth element out of these 99 variables.

How could I do that? And another question is: How will R handle the empty spaces? When I look at the variables with `dput(variable)`, each empty space is labelled as `" "`. (Could I replace them 0 in the final vector?)

I hope this is clear!

Thank you for your help! Regards

Comment: Something like `sapply(Romania_Pollen, "[", 3)` ...

Comment: Yes, this actually is it! Thank you! OMG! What does the "[" actually mean? thx

Comment: Study `help("[")`.

Comment: @Roland You should add that as an answer